# Facebook SSO, Android and authentication against Google App Engine

Tags: android, python, facebook, google-app-engine

I followed the tutorial here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso

I am able to authenticate on the android side, but what I want to do is to use SSO or some sort of authentication using facebook [preferrably OAuth] to authenticate against my web application on GAE. I expect it to work something like this: [blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app)

This is the sort of flow I expect:

1. The user starts my app, and is prompted with an option to `authenticate to FB`.
2. The FB app/web dialog opens and asks the user to confirm permissions to be given to my app.
3. Once that is done, FB provides me with a cookie [or something similar].
4. I use that cookie for subsequent requests to my web service, where I can get the username simply using:

> ```
> user = oauth.get_current_user()
> user.nickname()
> ```

Is anything like this possible? The problem I face is that while performing SSO, there is no place where I specify an OAuth end point. GAE provides OAuth endpoints [[http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html]](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview.html), which I think I should be using. Any clue as to how I can proceed about this?

Any help is appreciated. Regards, rohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the server-side authentication flow: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

I implemented it in Java: see the [LeanEngine](http://www.lean-engine.com) oss project. You could probably reuse the android client part: the [login dialog](https://github.com/leanengine/LeanEngine-Android/blob/master/lean-android-lib/src/main/java/com/leanengine/LoginDialog.java).

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late choice as an answer, but your code from git helped me a lot :) Thanks a lot..

Comment: @Peter, This was posted a while ago and I can see the project hasn't been updated for several years. Is the project still functional with recent SDKs and APIs? As far as you're aware is it stable? Do you have a recommended alternative? Thanks

Comment: It is not actively developed anymore. If you need a server-side auth flow you should look into pac4j: https://github.com/leleuj/pac4j